# why is Image.putpixel() not considered a good option for changing extensive pixel colors?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The documentation of `Image.putpixel()` states:-

> Modifies the pixel at the given position. The color is given as a single numerical value for single-band images, and a tuple for multi-band images.
>
> Note that this method is relatively slow. For more extensive changes, use `paste()` or the `ImageDraw` module instead.

Clearly, the documentation states that This method is relatively **slow**, and if the number of changes in the image are large one should consider other methods.

But there doesn't exists a clear reason, why?

I tried to do a source code analysis of the `putpixel()` method, but was unable to deduce anything.

**SOURCE OF `putpixel()`:-**

```
def putpixel(self, xy, value):

    if self.readonly:
        self._copy()
    self.load()

    if self.pyaccess:
        return self.pyaccess.putpixel(xy, value)

    if self.mode == "P" and isinstance(value, (list, tuple)) and len(value) in [3, 4]:
        # RGB or RGBA value for a P image
        value = self.palette.getcolor(value)
    return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
```

**P.S.:-** I was wondering whether `Image.getpixel()` (opposite method of `putpixel()`) suffers the same drawbacks too? As it has not been mentioned in its documentation.

Comment: Presumably, the other methods that do operations *in bulk* have ways to parallelize (or otherwise speed up) the operations, whereas doing so individually or manually would not yield the same benefits. As to what those other operations are, I dunno, you'd have to look at the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want six apples, it's way faster to go to the store once and buy six apples, than to go to the store six times and buy a single apple each time. The same is true for setting pixels.

Look at what the `putpixel` method is doing:

1. It does various checks like whether the image is read-only, whether the implementation uses pyaccess, and which color mode the image uses
2. It may check and verify the type and dimension of the pixel data
3. `self.im.putpixel` undoubtedly does the same to the coordinates, and multiples to find the offset
4. Finally it can do the actual operation: setting four bytes worth of pixel data.

That's dozen of operations, property accesses and method calls for a very small operation. If you call `putpixel` multiple times, it repeats all those operations every single time.

If you ask it to do multiple pixels at the same time, it can skip steps 1-3 for the next pixels because it'll be the same.